# Finding a certain block of code in text

Tags: python, tkinter, readline

I have the following code so far:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile # Open dialog box


fen1 = Tk()                              # Create window
fen1.title("Optimisation")               # Window title

menu1 = Menu(fen1)

def open():
    filename = askopenfile(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")], mode='r')

filename.seek(0)
    numligne = 0
    line     = []
    ok       = 0
    k        = -1

    while (ok == 0)  &  (k == -1):
    line = filename.readline()
    k    = line.find( "*load" )
    if k == 0 :
        l = filename.readlines()

fen1.mainloop()
```

The text file I am searching is in the format similar to below:

```
*test
1 2 3 4

*load
2 7 200
3 7 150

*stiffness
2 9 8 7

etc..
```

I've so far managed to find the line beginning with "*load" but I wish to assign the values in between '*load' and '*stiffness' to variables such as a, b, c. My problem is that in this load section, there could be several lines and I need to detect each one every time, split the values in the lines and give them a name. If someone could please help explain a loop or something similar that would do just the trick, I would be very grateful! Thank you!

UPDATE: I have the problem where I now want to find SEVERAL seperate sections in the same text file. How am I able to create a loop to further find lines between '*geo' and '*house', and also '*name' and '*surname'? I've tried to create an entirely separate definition but would like to minimize the lines of code I use...Thank you! Code I've been using the similar structure for (as provided for my original question, thanks to mgilson!) and would therefore like to edit these type of code.

```
def parse_file(ff):     
    out=[]     
    append=False     
    for line in ff:         
        if(append and line.strip()):
            out.append(line)          
            if(line.startswith('*load')): 
                append=True
            elif(line.startswith('*stiffness')):  
                return [map(int,x.split()) for x in out[:-1] ]
```

Comment: @Digitalis If you're talking about the word, `optimisation` is french for `optimization`. If not then, most probably yes, because that's what the window's title says. :P

Comment: Yeah, I'm switching between english and french...therefore I now get confused between various spellings..

Comment: :) Quite a funny word to spell wrong in that context. French makes sense indeed. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Check the update I made to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your "blocks" of code are separated by headers (e.g. `*header`).  The most intuitive way to store the data in each block is in a list of lists.  e.g. `[ row1, row2, ...]` (where `row1=[elem1,elem2,elem3,...]`).  Then you can store the block in a dictionary so you can get access to the block via `block=dictionary['headername']`.

This will do something like what you want (*this version is untested*).

```
import sys

def convert_type(ss):
    try:
        return int(ss)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(ss)
        except ValueError:
            return ss

def parse_file(ff):
    out={}
    block=None
    for i,line in enumerate(ff):
        #Allow for comments to start with '#'.  We break off anything after a '#'
        #and ignore it.  After that, we 
        data=line.split('#',1)
        line=data[0]  #comments (if in line) are in data[1] ... ignore those.
        line=line.strip() #remove whitespace from front and back of line.
        if(line.startswith('*')):
            #python supports multiple assignment.  
            #e.g. out['header'] is the same object as block.  
            #     changing block also changes out['header']
            block=out[line.strip()[1:]]=[]
        elif (block is not None) and line: #checks to make sure there is an active block and the line wasn't empty.
            #If the file could also have floats, you should use float instead of int
            #We also put the parsing in a try/except block.  If parsing fails (e.g. a
            #element can't be converted to a float, you'll know it and you'll know the
            #line which caused the problem.)
            try:
                #block.append(map(int,line.split()))
                block.append(map(convert_type,line.split()))  
            except Exception:
                sys.stderr.write("Parsing datafile choked on line %d '%s'\n"%(i+1,line.rstrip()))
                raise
    return out

with open('textfile.txt','r') as f:
    data_dict=parse_file(f)

#get information from '*load' block:
info=data_dict['load']
for row in info:
    a,b,c=row
    ##same as:
    #a=row[0]
    #b=row[1]
    #c=row[2]
    ##as long as row only has 3 elements.

    #Do something with that particular row. 
    #(each row in the 'load' block will be visited once in this loop)

#get info from stiffness block:
info=data_dict['stiffness']
for row in info:
    pass #Do something with this particular row.
```

Note that if you're guaranteed that each row in the datafile under a certain header has the same number of entries, you can think of the variable `info` as a 2-dimensional row which is indexed as `element=info[row_number][column_number]` -- but you can also get an entire row by `row=info[row_number]`

Comment: There wll always be 3 numbers in each row, it's the number of rows that could be of a random number.

Comment: @user20 -- Ok, that's good to know, but the point is how do you want the numbers stored?  Do you want 1 list?  or a list for each line?  My answer returns a list for each line, but I don't know if that's desireable or not.

Comment: I believe a list for each line would be more appropriate, thank you for your help =)

Comment: @user20 : I'm sorry.  I don't follow.  how could you get the values without the datafile?  you need the datafile in order to read the values from it (I thought).  Of course, you just need to parse it once and then the values are all there (in my example, they're in the variable `output`).

Comment: Also with this code, how would I assign the 'n' number of rows to values since there could be several. It's fair enough doing output[0], output[1] etc but if I have output[n], how could I do this?

Comment: @user20 -- that depends on what you want to do with each row.  If you can process one row at a time, you can pack it into a loop.  `for lst in output: a,b,c=lst; #....`

Comment: Will the loop then stop if it just doesn't find values? I'm really not very strong at python and don't quite understand how to 'create' this loop. Are you also able to help with the update in my question please?  It's a similar sort of loop situation possibly. I've been given this as a task so apologies for the lack of knowledge!

Comment: @user20 -- I've updated the code.  It should now be a lot more general -- In fact, it parses the entire file up front and stores the results in a python dictionary, so you can get the block of data from the dictionary like `block=data_dict['stiffness']`

Comment: I'm receiving a ValueError for an int with a base 10..?

Comment: @user20 -- It works for me on the test file you provided above.  Try printing `data_dict.keys()`

Comment: Does this work with decimal points? I think that may be where the problem is.

Comment: @user20 -- You mean with numbers that aren't integers in your datafile?  No.  to make it work, change `int` to `float` (see the comment in the line under "`elif (block is not None) and line:`"

Comment: Ok that worked but I completely forgot that in my text file that's given to me, there's always a date at the beginning in the format DD/MM/YY so it gets stumped at that..?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12551/discussion-between-mgilson-and-user20)

Comment: In fact, the newer text files I've been given aren't necessarily just numbers, I have letters here, there and everywhere. Is there any way of declaring this function for float, int and str?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
line = filename.readline()
if line.find("*load") == 0:
    line = filename.readline()
    while line != "\n" and line != "":
        vars = line.split(" ")
```

`vars` is just an example to store the values which would be `['2', '7', '200']` after this code runs (so you would need to convert them to floats or ints).  You could then append these to an array or rename them as needed.

EDIT: Working program derived from the above.

```
filename = open("fff.txt", 'r')
values = {}

line = filename.readline()
while line:
    while line.find("*") != 0:
        line = filename.readline()

    sectionheader = line.strip()[1:]
    values[sectionheader] = []
    line = filename.readline()
    while line != "\n" and line != "":
        vals = [float(i) for i in line.split(" ")]
        values[sectionheader].append(vals)
        line = filename.readline()

print values
```

Comment: `if line.find('*load'):` doesn't work.  When '*load' is found, the function returns 0 (if it's the first thing on the line).

Comment: whoops, wrote this too quickly and missed that. fixed.

Comment: What is the error?  It seemed to work on my end -- see the more complete example I just added.

Answer (score 0):

Though I cannot help you with the syntax, it is probably best to use self invokation.

Write a function that detects the line you need and store the byte offset.
Next, make that function invokate itself to find the next line ( to end the operation ), store its offset also and compare it with the previously saved value.

Now you have enough data to pinpoint which bytes need to be changed.

Self invoking functions are however quite efficient when used right they speed up performance and are easy to reuse.

In php I have build a streamwriter similar to the one in .net which works this way.
I therefore know the theory works, however, this seems to be python.

I don't know enough of that language unfortunately. Good luck with your project though!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I made of your code:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile # Open dialog box


fen1 = Tk()                              # Create window
fen1.title("Optimisation")               # Window title

menu1 = Menu(fen1)

def do_open(interesting_parts=[]):
    thefile = askopenfile(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")], mode='r')

    data = {} # Create a dictionary to store all the data stored per part name
    part = None
    for line in thefile:
        if line.startswith("*"):
            # A * in the beginning signals a new "part"
            # And another one means the end.
            part = line[1:] # Remove the * in the beginning via slicing to get the name without it.
            if part in interesting_parts:
                data[part] = [] # Create a list inside the dictionary, so that you can add data to it later.
                # Only do this if we are interested in storing anything for this part
        elif part in interesting_parts:
            # Add an a condition to check if the part name is in the list of "parts" you are interested in having.
            line_data = get_something_from_this(part, line) # just a function that returns something based on the line and the part
            if line_data is not None: # Ignore it if it's None (just an option, as there might be newlines that you want to ignore)
                data[part].append(line_data)

    # Here, we return the dictionary to act on it.
    return data

def get_something_from_this(part, line):
    try:
        ints = [int(p) for p in line.split()]
    except ValueError:
        print "Ignoring Line", repr(line), "in", part
        return None # We don't care about this line!
    else:
        print "in", part, ints
        return ints # Store this line's data

data = do_open(["test", "egg"]) # Pass as an argument a list of the interesting "parts"

print data # this is a dictionary

# How do you access it?
print data["test"] # to get all the lines' data in a list
print data["egg"][0] # to get the first line of the data

for part, datalines in data.iterkeys():
    print part, datalines # datalines is the list of all the data, part is the dictionary's key which is the part name
    # Remember data[part] = ... <- Here part is the key.

fen1.mainloop()
```

1. Don't name the variable filename when it's not a "file name" but a "file".
2. You can use the for loop to loop through the lines one by one.
3. Use split to split a string
4. Use startswith to know if a string starts with another string
5. Keep track of whether or not you're in the "*load" part in a variable.

**UPDATE**:
Don't use open as a function name, it's already in python's builtins.
Also, to avoid parsing the `*load` and `*stiffness` lines, I modified a bit the code: the parsing of each line is done in an `elif` statement.

**UPDATE 2**:

Updated code according to OP's needs. Tested with this file:

```
*test
1 2 3

*load
2 7 200
3 7 150

*stiffness
2 9 8

*egg
1 2 3
2 4 6

*plant
23 45 78
```

**UPDATE 3**: Heavily commented :)

Comment: I would just use `line.split()` instead of `line.split(" ")` (they're subtlely different).  But storing all the data in a dict is indeed the way to go for this.  (it's what I ended up doing for my edit as well).

Comment: I really like this method as well but am a bit confused as to where I can assign the values found to variables and also how to find the certain parts. E.g if I just wanted to find *test and *egg.

Comment: @mgilson Good to know there's a difference... I thought I'd make it more explicit.

Comment: @jadkik94 -- You can see the difference very quickly by trying this:   `"this  is a string  which sometimes has  2 spaces  in it".split(" ")` -- Hmmm... SO isn't preserving my multiple spaces very well...

Answer (score -2):

something like this should do

```
data=[]
check=false
for i in fid:
    if line.find("*load"):
        check=true
    if check==true and not line.find("*stiffness"):
        line=split(i)
        data.append(map(lambda x: float(x), line))
    if line.find("*stiffness"):
        break

fid.close()
for i in data:
    a=i[0]
    b=i[1]
    c=i[2]
```

take this as a code as rough suggestion ... (I think the exception is fixed now, well if not I don't care...)

Comment: I think your `map` will raise an exception when it comes across the '*stiffness' line.

Comment: Also your `if line.find(...)` should be `if line.find(...) == -1`